# Why command "go clean -n -r -i github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum..." does not work?

Tags: go, go-ethereum

What I did were as follows step by step:

1. Git clone go-ethereum project to my local PC. It is located in
   D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum. It is the source code
   of go-ethereum

   Note: The OS is windows 7. Go has already been installed. And GOPATH env has already been set to "D:\GOPATH"
2. cd /d D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum. Then execute
   "go install". Some exe files were genereated under D:\GOPATH\bin
   directory, and many pkg file with suffix .a were generated under
   D:\GOPATH\pkg directory. Everything seems no problem.
3. Execute "go clean -n -r -i github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum..." to
   remove all the generated exe files and .a files. But something very
   interesting happened:

In the command's log, it showed that some files are deleted, but actually they are not deleted from disk.

For example, event.a exists under D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum, but the log of "git clean" shows:"rm -f D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\event.a"

The detailed information is in the attached images.

It is very strange. The log does not match with the actual result:

A small segment of go clean command is as follows(since there are more than 1300 lines in log, I can not paste all of it):

> cd D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\event
>   rm -f event.test event.test.exe
>   rm -f D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\event.a
>   cd D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\common\mclock
>   rm -f mclock.test mclock.test.exe
>   rm -f D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\common\mclock.a
>   cd D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\vendor\github.com\aristanetworks\goarista\monotime
>   rm -f monotime.test monotime.test.exe
>   rm -f D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\vendor\github.com\aristanetworks\goarista\monotime.a
>   cd D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\accounts\abi
>   rm -f abi.test abi.test.exe
>   rm -f D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\accounts\abi.a
>   cd D:\GOPATH\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\accounts\abi\bind
>   rm -f bind.test bind.test.exe
>   rm -f D:\GOPATH\pkg\windows_amd64\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum\accounts\abi\bind.a

But some of the files remain:

[image]

Comment: OK, it is my first time to ask question in stackoverflow, so I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: "The -n flag causes clean to print the remove commands it would execute, but not run them."

Comment: Thank you very much.  @Peter I asked a silly question. Just now I tried -x and it works. I will close this question.

Answer (score -1):

The correct answer is actually provided by @Peter in comment. As Peter said "The -n flag causes clean to print the remove commands it would execute, but not run them."

I tried "-x" instead of "-n", and it works well. Thanks Peter. But you posted your answer in comment section, so I have to post your answer here and close this question.

Comment: Don't close the question because you got an answer--instead accept the correct answer.

Comment: OK, no problem. @Flimzy